# Ubuntu 12.04 on a Macbook Pro 2.66 core 2 duo

Tags: ubuntu, macbook-pro

I am trying to dual boot my mac book pro. It is running OS X Lion and the other half I've tried a couple of times to install the latest Ubuntu 12.04 using the 32bit version.

I went through the following tutorial as my install dual boot process.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/dual-boot-os-ubuntu/

All seems to go well during the install process and once I get back to the bootloader screen and choose Ubuntu for the first time and "boot" into it it actually seems to work but I think something may be wrong with the driver for the video card maybe ?

The only way I know to describe what I see is the screen just looks all jacked up. Most of it's purple with some random lines of black. I really would like to get this working as I think I could totally switch to the OS if I have some time to use it.

Here are the general specs on the Macbook Pro that I have http://grab.by/dmqi

Hoping someone has had some success dual booting this and can give me the step by step on getting it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are presented with the grub menu, press e. Look for the word "splash". Before that word, type in "nomodeset" without quotes.  So it would look something like "nomodeset splash" Press CTRL + X to boot.  Check out this page --> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir3-2/Narwhal

Comment: I found that I actually needed to add nouveau.noaccel=1 as an argument to the boot loading the first time till I could get the Nvidia drivers set up. After that everything worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've gone and given your mbp the free space, then run the CD/USB for Ubuntu and open up `gparted` (You may need to download this).

From there, create a partition of about 4gb and make it swap space, then format the remaining free space into ext4.

Now reinstall Ubuntu, and direct it to install on the ext4 partition and tick to format too (format it into ext4 again i believe).

Now you should be set up. Turn the MacBook Pro off, then on again (shutdown, DON'T reboot!) and then select Linux, and it should work fine. I get the banding issue but it lasts 2 seconds during the initial loadup.